# Normal mode in Math when assigning function

Tags: equations

I am curious about your thoughts of the use of math vs normal mode in this [Equation:](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Cbegin%7Bequation%7D%20%5Clabel%7Beq:4:6%7D%20%5Chat%7BP%7D%5E%7B%5Ctextnormal%7BNaive%5Ctextsubscript%7B3%7D%7D%7D_%7Bd,h%7D%20=%20%5Cbegin%7Bcases%7D%20P_%7Bd-7,h%7D,%5Cquad%20%5Ctextrm%7BDoW%7D(d)%20=%201,%206,%207%5C%5C%20P_%7Bd-1,h%7D,%5Cquad%20%5Ctextrm%7Botherwise%7D,%20%5Cend%7Bcases%7D%20%5Cend%7Bequation%7D)

```
\begin{equation} 
\hat{P}^{\textnormal{Naive\textsubscript{3}}}_{d,h} =
\begin{cases} 
P_{d-7,h},\quad \textrm{DoW}(d) = 1, 6, 7\\
P_{d-1,h},\quad \textrm{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

Where `DoW(d)` is a function of the `Day of the Week` that depends on `d` which takes the value 1 if Monday, 2 if Tuesday etc. I have heard that abbreviation in general short be in normal mode, but what about a function that is an abbreviation? I chose to put the `DoW` in normal mode and the `(d)` in math mode above, but I think it looks a bit funny.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can call your functions any way you like, so long as you clearly explain the notation.

Don't use `\textnormal` or `\textrm` for something that's mathematical in nature, such as textual superscripts or subscripts.

There's also no reason for `\textsubscript` in math mode.

As observed by eagle-eyed Mico, you should use `&` inside `cases` and not `\quad`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\DoW}{DoW} % similar to sin or log

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} 
\hat{P}^{\mathrm{Naive}_3}_{d,h} =
\begin{cases} 
P_{d-7,h}, & \DoW(d) = 1, 6, 7\\
P_{d-1,h}, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The input is even easier.

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd also be inclined to replace both instances of `\quad` with `&` to assure proper vertical alignment of the "if" compoments of the `cases` construct. (Right now, the alignment is there, but it's more by happy coincidence than by deliberate design.)

Comment: @Mico I didn't even see it.